# Having problems with sqlDataReader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatareader

I am using a sqlDataReader to get data and set it to session variables.  The problem is it doesn't want to work with expressions.  I can reference any other column in the table, but not the expressions.  The SQL does work.  The code is below.  Thanks in advance, Anthony

```
Using myConnectionCheck As New SqlConnection(myConnectionString)
    Dim myCommandCheck As New SqlCommand()
    myCommandCheck.Connection = myConnectionCheck
    myCommandCheck.CommandText = "SELECT Projects.Pro_Ver, Projects.Pro_Name, Projects.TL_Num, Projects.LP_Num, Projects.Dev_Num, Projects.Val_Num, Projects.Completed, Flow.Initiate_Date, Flow.Requirements, Flow.Req_Date, Flow.Dev_Review, Flow.Dev_Review_Date, Flow.Interface, Flow.Interface_Date, Flow.Approval, Flow.Approval_Date, Flow.Test_Plan, Flow.Test_Plan_Date, Flow.Dev_Start, Flow.Dev_Start_Date, Flow.Val_Start, Flow.Val_Start_Date, Flow.Val_Complete, Flow.Val_Complete_Date, Flow.Stage_Production, Flow.Stage_Production_Date, Flow.MKS, Flow.MKS_Date, Flow.DIET, Flow.DIET_Date, Flow.Closed, Flow.Closed_Date, Flow.Dev_End, Flow.Dev_End_Date, Users_1.Email AS Expr1, Users_2.Email AS Expr2, Users_3.Email AS Expr3, Users_4.Email AS Expr4, Users_4.FNAME, Users_3.FNAME AS Expr5, Users_2.FNAME AS Expr6, Users_1.FNAME AS Expr7 FROM Projects INNER JOIN Users AS Users_1 ON Projects.TL_Num = Users_1.PIN INNER JOIN Users AS Users_2 ON Projects.LP_Num = Users_2.PIN INNER JOIN Users AS Users_3 ON Projects.Dev_Num = Users_3.PIN INNER JOIN Users AS Users_4 ON Projects.Val_Num = Users_4.PIN INNER JOIN Flow ON Projects.id = Flow.Flow_Pro_Num WHERE id = "
    myCommandCheck.CommandText += QSid
    myConnectionCheck.Open()
    myCommandCheck.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Dim count As Int16 = myCommandCheck.ExecuteScalar
    If count = 1 Then
        Dim myDataReader As SqlDataReader
        myDataReader = myCommandCheck.ExecuteReader()
        While myDataReader.Read()
            Session("TL_email") = myDataReader("Expr1").ToString()
            Session("PE_email") = myDataReader("Expr2").ToString()
            Session("DEV_email") = myDataReader("Expr3").ToString()
            Session("VAL_email") = myDataReader("Expr4").ToString()
            Session("Project_Name") = myDataReader("Pro_Name").ToString()
        End While
        myDataReader.Close()
    End If
End Using
```

Comment: Are you getting back more than one record?
Can you explain what you mean by it does not work? Are you seeing an error?

Comment: As a side note, you may want to  parametrize your query.  Currently it is open to SQL injection because you are concatenating QSID which may be coming from user input.

Comment: Raj, I am only getting one record.  What I mean by it doesn't work is that the Session variables are blank when I call them.  The only error I get is when I try to send an email and use the session variables as parameters for the from and to.  It says the parameter can't be blank

Comment: Jon, I don't know exactly what you are talking about.  But QSID contains the value of a querystring.

Comment: Do **NOT** call executenonquery and executescalar in addition to executereader.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because column names need to be unique for the SqlDataReader to be able to index them using a string name for the column.

Comment: Ok. So do you have a suggestion on how I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) You are executing the query 3 times. You can lose the ExecuteNonQuery and ExecuteScalar calls, and replace the while loop with "if myDataReader.Read() / end if" to get the data values for the first resulting record. If no records are found, no session variables are set, just as in your current code.

2) It looks more like the problem lies in your session management (ie getting values *from* Session) rather than your sql query, which looks OK to me.

Check:

- that you have sessionState enabled in your web.config file,
- that you don't reset the Session values anywhere, and
- that you ask for the same Session field name when you are trying to send the email. (e.g. are you setting Session("DEV_Email") but asking for Session("DEV Email") (space instead of underscore) ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone.  The code works just fine.  The sqlDataReader WILL accept expressions as column names.

The reason I was getting an error saying the value of the from and to parameters cannot be null.  There was no data in that column for any of the records in my table.